Widgets in a Flutter row are too big that causes overflow horizontally
I'm having trouble figuring out how to layout the widgets in a row so that they won't overflow. I have a Column that contains a row taking all the space except a Card at bottom. Within the Row, I have a List View on the left and a fixed size widget on the right. That causes overflow horizontally. I tried to wrap the Row with a SingleChildScrollView but that didn't help. Here is my code snippet.
  import 'package: flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: ' Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 getCard(int level){
    double indentation=5.0*level;
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: indentation),
      child: Card(
        color: const Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text('List Item ${level + 1}'), //  title
          subtitle: Text('Description for List Item ${level + 1}'), //   subtitle
          dense: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  getListView(){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 25, // Number of items in the list
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap:(){
            setState(() {
             });
          },
          child: getCard(index),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
         child: Column(
           children: [
           Expanded(
             child: ListView(
               shrinkWrap: true,
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               children: [
                getListView(),
                const SizedBox(width:2000,
                  child: Text("A widget with a large size width"),
                ),
               ],
             ),
           ),
           const Text("this needs to be at the bottom of the screen"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
     );
  }
}


Do you want the widgets in the Row to scroll horizontally?

yes.  That's what I want. I tried to put them in a List and SingleChildScrollView horizontally but I can't make it work.

Okay, can you modify your code to a minimum reproducible example so it can be run? It will make it easier to answer this question.

Try adding SizedBox with width set to screen width to your ListView or get ListView() implementation . Alternatively, if you use ListView set shrinkwrap to true.

have you tried SingleChildScrollView with scrollDireection : Axis.Horizontal  ?

It is not clear what you want to achieve. Do you want  also the WaveSlider widget to be scrollable or do you want it to take a fraction of the width and the rest to be the ListView?

Thanks for looking into this. I updated with reproducible example. I tried changing row with ListView along with shrinkwrap, wrapping Row with SingleChildScrollView.  In the sample code, I replaced WaveSlider with a SizedBox to make it simple to view.

I think that issue is with placing a vertical ListView inside of a horizontal ListView. I still can't find a solution for it. For now, I just have to separate the 2 ListView apart.

There are several issues with your code.
ListView.builder cannot be used with unbounded width or height. You need to define definite height for ListView.builder.
    getListView() {
        return Container(
         height: 200,
         width: 320
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 25, // Number of items in the list
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: getCard(index),
            );
          },
        );
       )
      }

